# Proving sin or cos series without derivative

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a way to prove that for instance: $$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+...=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$
Without using derivatives? In other words, to do it without using what we know from Maclaurin or Taylor series.

Comment: Which definition of $\sin$ and $\cos$ do you have in mind?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. But just to prove that either cos or sin can be written as series

Comment: There is *nothing* that we can prove about either of them unless we define them in some way.

Answer (score 1):

This series has Laplace transform
$$\int_0^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n} \mathrm{e}^{-sx} \mathrm{d} x =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} \int_{0}^\infty x^{2n} \mathrm{e}^{-sx} \mathrm{d} x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} \frac{(2n)!}{s^{2n+1}}=\frac{1}{s} \frac{1}{1+1/s^2}=\frac{s}{s^2+1} $$
for $\Re (s)>0$. Using the partial fractions decomposition

$$\frac{s}{s^2+1}=\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{s-i}+\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{s+i}, $$
and the inverse Laplace transform, we get $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{(2n)!}=\frac{1}{2} \left( \mathrm{e}^{ix}+\mathrm{e}^{-ix} \right) $$
for positive $x$. Analytic continuation implies the two functions coincide for all $x \in \mathbb{C}$.